# VS Code Extension, How to handle Events when a View is activated?

Tags: visual-studio-code, view, event-handling, vscode-extensions

Testing a VS Code extension
The package.json creates a View in the Explorer with id "Test"

```
"contributes": {
    "views": {
        "explorer": [
            {
                "id": "Files",
                "name": "Files Test"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This successfully generates the view "Files Test" in the Explorer

And according to [this link activating the view will emit an activationEvent](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.views)  `onView:${viewID}`

Question: How do you detect and handle this even on the JS code for this extension?

(I'm familiar with handling the "Hello World" activation event, but so far no luck with event handling for Views)

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? Handling this activation event is no different from handling any other, they all result in `activate()` being called.

Comment: @Gama11 Makes sense.  By 'no luck' -- opening the View isn't yet triggering the intended command registered in the JS.  I think I'm not yet understanding the relationship between activationEvents,  contributes.views, & contributes.command.  Based on the contributes.views.explorer.id ("Files") shown above, how would you register the command?

Comment: Well, `onView:Files`.